# ViewDidAppear and textFiedlDidEndEditing control flow

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a push segue from a UITableViewController to another UITableViewController. An object is passed to the second VC via `prepareForSegue`. A UITextfield exists in the second VC to edit that object. The object is modified in the second VC's `textFiedlDidEndEditing` delegate method. Rather than creating a delegate method, I simply placed `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the first VC's `viewDidAppear` method to update the table which displays the object.

When a user navigates back to the first VC, I need to be sure that `viewDidAppear` in the first VC will be called only after the second VC's `textFiedlDidEndEditing` has completed and set the new object. It seems to be working this way, but it this because of chance or because `viewDidAppear` is only called after the previous VC's method's have implemented?

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidAppear` will be called when your first view has re-appeared on the screen. I assume you are programmatically popping the second view controller or using the unwind segue. If this is the case then call

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

in your second VC.

Comment: I'm noticing when the back button navigation item is tapped in the VC with the textField, the first VC's `viewWillAppear` is being called before `textFieldDidEndEditing`. I'd like to place my `reloadData` call in `viewWillAppear`, but my object is not modified yet when it is fired.

Comment: I figured it out and posted my solution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In the textfield's VC, I had to place the below code to ensure `textFieldDidEndEditing` gets called before any other VC's `viewWillAppear` method.

```
[self.view.window endEditing: YES];
```